# C# How do I Access this generic list, when i didn't create the type?

Tags: c#, list

I've stepped through the first part and that works correctly. My list ends up As `fileName[288]`, and in my locals window I have a "value". This is a list. I didn't create the type, so I don't know how to access it. I know it is a generic list of strings, so I imported S`ystem.Collections.Generic.List`, but I cant seem to figure it out.

```
var fileName = new DirectoryInfo(text)
   .GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .Select(x => x.Name)
   .ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < fileName.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Filename: {0}", fileName[i].?)
}
```

Comment: Why not just `fileName[i]` ?

Comment: `.Select(x => x.Name)`: since `x` is of type `string` you have `fileName` of type `List<string>`, so `Console.WriteLine("Filename: {0}", fileName[i])`

Comment: When you write `fileName[i].` IntelliSense gives you all the options for a `string`. In this case, you would just do `fileName[i]` since that's the data you likely want. Also, you shouldn't copy paste code you don't understand.

Comment: @ Camilo Terevinto - I know but my code to do the same thing was about 60 lines compared to 3. I was trying to make it better, at least now I know I really need to study generics.

Comment: Yeah, you won't get far without a good knowledge of generics in c#. The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) are pretty good explaining the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the *last* `Select` returns `string` (`x.Name` is of type `string`)

```
...  
.Select(x => x.Name) // select string(s)
.ToList();           // materialize them into a list
```

then `fileName` is of type `List<string>` and you have no need in any additional method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Filename: {0}", fileName[i]);
```

I suggest getting rid of `for loop` and let (with a help of `foreach`) .Net work for you:

```
// we have (potentially) many files' names - let use "fileNames" - plural
var fileNames = new DirectoryInfo(text)
   .GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .Select(x => x.Name);

foreach (var name in fileNames)
    Console.WriteLine($"Filename: {name}"); // string interpolation for readability
```

**Edit:** Please, notice that we don't need `.ToList()` in case of `foreach` - all we want is to *enumerate the names* without saving them into an any collection (say `List<string>`).